# jquery "hasClass" no funciona

Tags: jquery

*** EDITADO EL CÓDIGO HTML ***
es un wordpress. He tenido que reescribir el menú para que pudierais verlo. He cometido un error a la hora de copiarlo.

Estoy montando mi menú de navegación y no encuentro el problema al siguiente código para que se me abra el menú desplegable.
El tema es que cuando abro el inspector de elementos si se "ilumina" el elemento al que se tiene que añadir la clase pero no lo hace. Si hago comprobaciones con `console.log` si me funciona.

Alguna ayuda? este es el código

```
    jQuery('.nav-icon').click(function(){

       if ( jQuery('.menu-header-menu-container').hasClass('open-nav') ) {
         jQuery('.menu-header-menu-container').removeClass('open-nav');

      } else {
         jQuery('.menu-header-menu-container').addClass('open-nav');
      }

       jQuery(this).toggleClass('opened');
    });
```

código HTML

```
<div class="masthead container">
  <div class="masthead-nav">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">GlobalDisplays</a></h1>

    <div class="masthead-block">
        <nav class="menu-header-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-header-menu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">Trabajos</a></li>
                <li><a href="agencia.html">La Agencia</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"><span>Productos</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.boxpromotions.com/shops/catalogo.asp" target="_blank">Mkt Promocional</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://pendrivesusb.com/?p=b034424f6c362cbb5c402cee220d2b1f" target="_blank">USB</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.catalogoblancodebanderas.com/" target="_blank">Banderas y soportes exteriores</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="search-icon"></div>

        <div class="nav-icon">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es el código que tengo en el functions. Yo creo que está todo bien. No se que opinais:

```
function gd_load_scripts(){

    /*  ====== CSS ======  */
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.min.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-theme-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.theme.default.min.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );

    /*  ====== GOOGLE FONTS ======  */
    wp_enqueue_style( 'open-sans', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,400i,700' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'raleway', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700' );


    /*  ====== JS ======  */
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery_google','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js',array(),null,true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_google' );

    wp_register_script( 'owl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery_google'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl' );

    wp_register_script( 'app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.min.js', array('jquery_google'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'app' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gd_load_scripts' );
```

El siguientes es el correspondiente a los span:

```
.nav-icon {
    display: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: rem(24);
    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-icon span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
    border-radius: 9px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Deberias de incluir tu HTML

Comment: `'.nav-icon'` hace referencia a los elementos con clase `nav-icon` (`class=nav-icon`), pero en tu codigo solo veo un div con `id=nav-icon`

Comment: el remove saca la class tenga o no la tenga, el if no haría falta, podes usar toggle, por otro lado no hay elementos `.nav-icon` clickeables. seguro es el html correcto?

Comment: Como dice @lealceldeiro, funciona si cambias `jQuery('.nav-icon').click(function(){` y pones `jQuery('#nav-icon').click(function(){`. El selector está mal.

Comment: @aloMalbarez ya he usado toggle y tampoco me funciona. Me resulta raro porque ya he empleado la misma estructura de menú y el mismo código de jquery para otra página que monté...

Answer (score 0):

Considera esto un comentario interactivo,

en tu código el `<div class="nav-icon">` no tiene contenido por lo cual es difícil hacerle click.

El resto del funcionamiento es lo esperado

```js
jQuery('.nav-icon').click(function(){

       if ( jQuery('.menu-header-menu-container').hasClass('open-nav') ) {
         jQuery('.menu-header-menu-container').removeClass('open-nav');

      } else {
         jQuery('.menu-header-menu-container').addClass('open-nav');
      }

       jQuery(this).toggleClass('opened');
    });
```

```css
.open-nav{
color: #f00;
}
.opened {
background: #fe0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="masthead container">
  <div class="masthead-nav">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">GlobalDisplays</a></h1>

    <div class="masthead-block">
        <nav class="menu-header-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-header-menu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">Trabajos</a></li>
                <li><a href="agencia.html">La Agencia</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"><span>Productos</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.boxpromotions.com/shops/catalogo.asp" target="_blank">Mkt Promocional</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://pendrivesusb.com/?p=b034424f6c362cbb5c402cee220d2b1f" target="_blank">USB</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.catalogoblancodebanderas.com/" target="_blank">Banderas y soportes exteriores</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="search-icon"></div>

        <div class="nav-icon">
            <span>click aca</span>
            <span>o aca</span>
            <span>o en realidad todo el renglón</span>
            <span>pues el div ocupa el ancho</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pero @aloMalbarez, eso de que no tiene contenido es relativo. Tiene tres span que con css le "agrego" contenido. Cuando la pantalla llega a un determinado tamaño me aparece el icono del menú que mide 25x25px

Comment: vale, el ejemplo es para demostrar que el código funciona como se espera. le puse contenido para poder clickarlo, y unos estilos para ver que se aplican las clases. el fondo amarillo es el hasclass, el color rojo en los list es el toggle.

Comment: siendo que es un wordpress habría que ver si el javascript se carga luego de que el menu existe en el DOM y  como dato adicional ayudaría ver cómo es que se rellenan los span